# Ruby on Rails 2.3.5: update_all failing on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update a collection of records in my database using ActiveRecord's update_all. Enter script/console.

```
MyModel.update_all("reserved = 1", :order => 'rand()', :limit => 1000)
```

ActiveRecord thinks order is a column, says it's unknown and throws an exception. According to the documentation though, my syntax looks sane. This is RoR 2.3.5.

When doing `MyModel.update_all("reserved = 1")` alone, it works just fine.

Also if I do

> > MyModel.update_all("reserved = 1", "reserve_type = 2", :order => "rand()", :limit => 1000)
> >     => 0

0 rows affected.

I'm simply trying to do: `UPDATE MyModel SET reserved=1, reserve_type=2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the second parameter of `update_all` should be conditions, you need to pass an empty hash like this:

```
MyModel.update_all("reserved = 1", {}, {:order => 'rand()', :limit => 1000})
```

This should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification on Jakub's response, the correct format should be:

```
MyModel.update_all("reserved = 1, reserve_type = 2", {}, {:order => 'rand()', :limit => 1000})
```

If you're updating multiple columns, the first parameter must contain the column list separated by commas.